# Element <li> could not be scrolled into view

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on size from drop down from this particular [website](https://18montrose.com/collections/footwear-mens), but I'm not able to do that.

```
size = wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'UK 6'))).click();
```

Comment: Please share which code you have tried and which exception you have got. If you do not found any error, then please share steps that you follows.

Answer (score 1):

1. Here, the elements of the list don't have any tag name "UK 6". Rather it's a text inside <**li**> tag.

[image]

You can find the element by searching on whether the element contains text "UK 6". The **XPATH** for finding the element would be:

```
//li[contains(.,'UK 6')]
```

2. Another mistake you have done is you are waiting for the element with **invisibility_of_element_located**. That means you are waiting for the element to be invisible. It should be **visibility_of_element_located** according to your need I think.

So the code would be:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//li[contains(.,'UK 6')]'))).click()
```